# Adding two Queries Together Using

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum, union, union-all

I know this has been asked before but I am having trouble following. 
I have 2 queries. One returning the sum of the value of quotes with a 10% rating and the other the sum of the value of quotes with a 20% rating. However I am trying to return the total of both values added together. 
My query so far is:

```
SELECT SUM(total) FROM (

SUM(dbo.QuoteLines.UQMLQUOTEVALUE*0.10) AS "10%" 
FROM ((dbo.Quotes LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.QuoteLines ON dbo.Quotes.qmpQuoteID = dbo.QuoteLines.qmlQuoteID) LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Followups ON dbo.QuoteLines.qmlQuoteID = dbo.Followups.cmfQuoteID)    WHERE  dbo.Quotes.qmpClosed  =  0 AND dbo.Quotes.UQMPFORWARDEDTOCUSTOMER  =  -1 AND dbo.QuoteLines.UQMLSALESSTAGE  =  1 AND dbo.Followups.cmfStatus  <  3 AND dbo.QuoteLines.qmlResolutionReasonID  =  ''

UNION ALL

SUM(dbo.QuoteLines.UQMLQUOTEVALUE*0.20) AS "20%" 
FROM ((dbo.Quotes LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.QuoteLines ON dbo.Quotes.qmpQuoteID = dbo.QuoteLines.qmlQuoteID) LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Followups ON dbo.QuoteLines.qmlQuoteID = dbo.Followups.cmfQuoteID)    WHERE  dbo.Quotes.qmpClosed  =  0 AND dbo.Quotes.UQMPFORWARDEDTOCUSTOMER  =  -1 AND dbo.QuoteLines.UQMLSALESSTAGE  =  2 AND dbo.Followups.cmfStatus  <  3 AND dbo.QuoteLines.qmlResolutionReasonID  =  ''
)a
```

But apparently I have an incorrect syntax near FROM.

Any ideas please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the correct syntax for using `UNION ALL` is

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
     SELECT col1, col2 FROM TABLE1
     UNION ALL
     SELECT col1, col2 FROM TABLE2
) AS alias
```

The query that you posted does not make sense to me, so not sure how to correct it

Your 2 query looks pretty similar with only difference in the `UQMLSALESSTAGE`.  Probably this is what you want. And you don't need to use `union`

```
SELECT  SUM(dbo.QuoteLines.UQMLQUOTEVALUE * 
            CASE WHEN dbo.QuoteLines.UQMLSALESSTAGE = 1 THEN 0.10 ELSE 0.20 END) AS Total
FROM    dbo.Quotes 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.QuoteLines  ON dbo.Quotes.qmpQuoteID = dbo.QuoteLines.qmlQuoteID
        LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Followups   ON dbo.QuoteLines.qmlQuoteID = dbo.Followups.cmfQuoteID
WHERE   dbo.Quotes.qmpClosed  =  0 
AND     dbo.Quotes.UQMPFORWARDEDTOCUSTOMER  = -1 
AND     dbo.QuoteLines.UQMLSALESSTAGE       IN ( 1 , 2 )
AND     dbo.Followups.cmfStatus             <  3 
AND     dbo.QuoteLines.qmlResolutionReasonID =  ''
```

Comment: Thank you, this shows no error, but only gives me a value for the first query.

Comment: You need to include some sample data and expected result in your question and explain the required logic or calculation to derived at the required result. As it is, we does not know what you want and can only help to resolve your syntax error

Comment: You are a genius! Solved thank you so much! I can't even describe how relieved I am right now.

Answer (score 0):

Your have issue with your script. Please try with below script-

```
SELECT SUM(total) FROM (
    SELECT
    SUM(dbo.QuoteLines.UQMLQUOTEVALUE*0.10) AS total
    FROM dbo.Quotes 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.QuoteLines 
        ON dbo.Quotes.qmpQuoteID = dbo.QuoteLines.qmlQuoteID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Followups 
        ON dbo.QuoteLines.qmlQuoteID = dbo.Followups.cmfQuoteID    
    WHERE  dbo.Quotes.qmpClosed  =  0 
    AND dbo.Quotes.UQMPFORWARDEDTOCUSTOMER  =  -1 
    AND dbo.QuoteLines.UQMLSALESSTAGE  =  1 
    AND dbo.Followups.cmfStatus  <  3 
    AND dbo.QuoteLines.qmlResolutionReasonID  =  ''

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
    SUM(dbo.QuoteLines.UQMLQUOTEVALUE*0.20) AS total 
    FROM dbo.Quotes 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.QuoteLines 
        ON dbo.Quotes.qmpQuoteID = dbo.QuoteLines.qmlQuoteID 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Followups 
        ON dbo.QuoteLines.qmlQuoteID = dbo.Followups.cmfQuoteID    
    WHERE  dbo.Quotes.qmpClosed  =  0 
    AND dbo.Quotes.UQMPFORWARDEDTOCUSTOMER  =  -1 
    AND dbo.QuoteLines.UQMLSALESSTAGE  =  2 
    AND dbo.Followups.cmfStatus  <  3 
    AND dbo.QuoteLines.qmlResolutionReasonID  =  ''
)a
```

Comment: Thank you mkRabbani, this shows no error now, but only shows me a value for the 1st query? Not a sum of the two.

Answer (score 0):

there is not found total field, join table is wrong

may be you can try this

```
SELECT SUM(total) FROM (

SUM(dbo.QuoteLines.UQMLQUOTEVALUE*0.10) total 
FROM ((select dbo.QuoteLines.UQMLQUOTEVALUE from dbo.Quotes LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.QuoteLines ON dbo.Quotes.qmpQuoteID = dbo.QuoteLines.qmlQuoteID) LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Followups ON dbo.QuoteLines.qmlQuoteID = dbo.Followups.cmfQuoteID)   WHERE  dbo.Quotes.qmpClosed  =  0 AND dbo.Quotes.UQMPFORWARDEDTOCUSTOMER  =  -1 AND dbo.QuoteLines.UQMLSALESSTAGE  =  1 AND dbo.Followups.cmfStatus  <  3 AND dbo.QuoteLines.qmlResolutionReasonID  =  ''

UNION ALL

SUM(dbo.QuoteLines.UQMLQUOTEVALUE*0.20) total
FROM ((select dbo.QuoteLines.UQMLQUOTEVALUE from dbo.Quotes LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.QuoteLines ON dbo.Quotes.qmpQuoteID = dbo.QuoteLines.qmlQuoteID) LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Followups ON dbo.QuoteLines.qmlQuoteID = dbo.Followups.cmfQuoteID)    WHERE  dbo.Quotes.qmpClosed  =  0 AND dbo.Quotes.UQMPFORWARDEDTOCUSTOMER  =  -1 AND dbo.QuoteLines.UQMLSALESSTAGE  =  2 AND dbo.Followups.cmfStatus  <  3 AND dbo.QuoteLines.qmlResolutionReasonID  =  ''
)a
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT SUM(total) FROM (
select 
SUM(dbo.QuoteLines.UQMLQUOTEVALUE*0.10) AS "total" 
From dbo.Quotes LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.QuoteLines ON dbo.Quotes.qmpQuoteID = dbo.QuoteLines.qmlQuoteID
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Followups ON dbo.QuoteLines.qmlQuoteID = dbo.Followups.cmfQuoteID    WHERE  dbo.Quotes.qmpClosed  =  0 
AND dbo.Quotes.UQMPFORWARDEDTOCUSTOMER  =  -1 AND dbo.QuoteLines.UQMLSALESSTAGE  =  1 AND dbo.Followups.cmfStatus  <  3 AND dbo.QuoteLines.qmlResolutionReasonID  =  ''

UNION ALL
select 
SUM(dbo.QuoteLines.UQMLQUOTEVALUE*0.20) AS "total" 
FROM dbo.Quotes LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.QuoteLines ON dbo.Quotes.qmpQuoteID = dbo.QuoteLines.qmlQuoteID
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Followups ON dbo.QuoteLines.qmlQuoteID = dbo.Followups.cmfQuoteID  
WHERE  dbo.Quotes.qmpClosed  =  0 AND dbo.Quotes.UQMPFORWARDEDTOCUSTOMER  =  -1 AND dbo.QuoteLines.UQMLSALESSTAGE  =  2 AND dbo.Followups.cmfStatus  <  3 AND dbo.QuoteLines.qmlResolutionReasonID  =  ''
)a
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code inside the `FROM ()a` is incomplete.  You might try extracting that code and running it by itself.  For example:

```
SUM(dbo.QuoteLines.UQMLQUOTEVALUE*0.10) AS "10%" 
FROM ((dbo.Quotes LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.QuoteLines ON dbo.Quotes.qmpQuoteID = dbo.QuoteLines.qmlQuoteID) LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Followups ON dbo.QuoteLines.qmlQuoteID = dbo.Followups.cmfQuoteID)    WHERE  dbo.Quotes.qmpClosed  =  0 AND dbo.Quotes.UQMPFORWARDEDTOCUSTOMER  =  -1 AND dbo.QuoteLines.UQMLSALESSTAGE  =  1 AND dbo.Followups.cmfStatus  <  3 AND dbo.QuoteLines.qmlResolutionReasonID  =  ''

UNION ALL

SUM(dbo.QuoteLines.UQMLQUOTEVALUE*0.20) AS "20%" 
FROM ((dbo.Quotes LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.QuoteLines ON dbo.Quotes.qmpQuoteID = dbo.QuoteLines.qmlQuoteID) LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Followups ON dbo.QuoteLines.qmlQuoteID = dbo.Followups.cmfQuoteID)    WHERE  dbo.Quotes.qmpClosed  =  0 AND dbo.Quotes.UQMPFORWARDEDTOCUSTOMER  =  -1 AND dbo.QuoteLines.UQMLSALESSTAGE  =  2 AND dbo.Followups.cmfStatus  <  3 AND dbo.QuoteLines.qmlResolutionReasonID  =  ''
```

That code doesn't work on its own because the `SELECT` is missing.  If you fix that and then insert the code back into the `FROM ()a` then I think you'll be in good shape.  For example:

```
SELECT SUM(total) FROM (
SELECT
SUM(dbo.QuoteLines.UQMLQUOTEVALUE*0.10) AS "10%" 
FROM ((dbo.Quotes LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.QuoteLines ON dbo.Quotes.qmpQuoteID = dbo.QuoteLines.qmlQuoteID) LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Followups ON dbo.QuoteLines.qmlQuoteID = dbo.Followups.cmfQuoteID)    WHERE  dbo.Quotes.qmpClosed  =  0 AND dbo.Quotes.UQMPFORWARDEDTOCUSTOMER  =  -1 AND dbo.QuoteLines.UQMLSALESSTAGE  =  1 AND dbo.Followups.cmfStatus  <  3 AND dbo.QuoteLines.qmlResolutionReasonID  =  ''

UNION ALL
SELECT
SUM(dbo.QuoteLines.UQMLQUOTEVALUE*0.20) AS "20%" 
FROM ((dbo.Quotes LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.QuoteLines ON dbo.Quotes.qmpQuoteID = dbo.QuoteLines.qmlQuoteID) LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Followups ON dbo.QuoteLines.qmlQuoteID = dbo.Followups.cmfQuoteID)    WHERE  dbo.Quotes.qmpClosed  =  0 AND dbo.Quotes.UQMPFORWARDEDTOCUSTOMER  =  -1 AND dbo.QuoteLines.UQMLSALESSTAGE  =  2 AND dbo.Followups.cmfStatus  <  3 AND dbo.QuoteLines.qmlResolutionReasonID  =  ''
)a
```